# while looping w3-quarter in w3-row-padding

Tags: php, css, while-loop

Here is the problem that while looping the php in while loop in w3-row-padding of w3 responsive layout . The layout breaks[image]

Here is the source code

```
    <?php 
$r=0;
 while($r<ceil($fetch_row_count/4)) 

              { ?>
      <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-16 w3-center" style="clear:both" id="food">
          <?php 

          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 

              {

         ?>
        <div class="w3-quarter">
            <img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" alt="noodles" style="width:50%">
          <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
          <p><?php echo $row['description']; ?> </p>
        </div>

        <?php






              }
              $r++;
              }
              ?>

      </div>
```

Thanks for reply and comments in advance

Comment: $fetch_row_count  is the count(*) of the mysql number or records

Comment: how is it breaking, how do you want it displayed?

Comment: clear both has solved the issue using css

Answer (score 0):

That bottom div was not being added for each of your padded containers.

The way the code is written you are adding a padded container and then adding your w3-quarter div for each of your result sets and then repeating that a bunch of times with what looks like to me the same set of data in each one.

What you are probably trying to accomplish is just making one padded div and then echo out your result set with the w3-quarter divs inside of it.

Here is your original way with the bottom div corrected:

```
<?php 

$r=0;
while($r<ceil($fetch_row_count/4)) {

  echo        
  '<div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-16 w3-center" style="clear:both" id="food">';

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

    echo      
    '<div class="w3-quarter">' .
    '<img src="admin/uploads/' . $row['image'] . '" alt="noodles" style="width:50%">' .
    '<h3>' . $row['title'] . '</h3>' .
    '<p>' . $row['description'] . '</p>' .
    '</div>';

    }

  $r++;

  echo
  '</div>';

}          

?>
```

Here is the way I think you are trying to do it: (Just guessing)

```
    <?php 

  echo        
  '<div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-16 w3-center" style="clear:both" id="food">';

    $r = 0;    
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

      echo      
      '<div class="w3-quarter">' .
      '<img src="admin/uploads/' . $row['image'] . '" alt="noodles" style="width:50%">' .
      '<h3>' . $row['title'] . '</h3>' .
      '<p>' . $row['description'] . '</p>' .
      '</div>';

      $r++;
      //I would not actually try to control how many results you add like this.
      //I would get the results from a better formatted query.
      if($r < ceil($fetch_row_count/4)){

      break;

      }

    }

  echo
  '</div>';

?>
```